# Problem establishing connection to InterBase database using C# (VS2017)

Tags: c#, database, connection, interbase

I am trying to connect my C# program to InterBase but i get the following error:

Borland.Data.TDBXError occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unable to load dbxint.dll (ErrorCode 193).  It may be missing from the system path.
  Source=Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver

I've tried so many methods but none of them have worked so far. Of them all, this one looks more promising. I installed the ADO_NET 2_0 Driver for InterBase and when i try to connect to the database I get this error:

```
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unable to load dbxint.dll (ErrorCode 193).  It may be missing from the system path.
  Source=Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver
  StackTrace:
   at Borland.Data.TDBXContext.Error(Int32 ErrorCode, String ErrorMessage)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverCommonLoader.LoadDriverLibrary(TDBXProperties DriverProperties, TDBXContext DBXContext)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverCommonLoader.LoadDriverLibraryAndMethodTable(TDBXContext DBXContext, TDBXProperties Properties)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverCommonLoader.Load(TDBXDriverDef DriverDef)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXDriverRegistry.LoadDriver(TDBXDriverDef DriverDef, TList List)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXDriverRegistry.GetDriver(TDBXDriverDef DriverDef)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXConnectionFactory.GetDriver(String DriverName, TDBXProperties DriverProperties)
   at Borland.Data.TDBXConnectionBuilder.CreateConnection()
   at Borland.Data.TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection(TDBXContext DBXContext, TDBXProperties ConnectionProperties)
   at Borland.Data.TAdoDbxConnection.Open()
   at IB2._0.Form1.ReadData(DbConnection conn) in D:\C#\IB2.0\IB2.0\Form1.cs:line 36
   at IB2._0.Form1..ctor() in D:\C#\IB2.0\IB2.0\Form1.cs:line 18
   at IB2._0.Program.Main() in D:\C#\IB2.0\IB2.0\Program.cs:line 14
```

I don't know if I'm looking for this file in the wrong directory, but this file is there in my project's bin folder.

My code is shown below, may you kindly assist.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Borland.Data;
using Borland.Vcl;
using Borland.Data.Units;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace IB2._0 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadData(getConnection());
        }

        public DbConnection getConnection() {
            // DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory
            //            ("Borland.Data.AdoDbxClient");
            DbConnection c = new TAdoDbxConnection();
            //DbConnection c = factory.CreateConnection();
            c.ConnectionString = "DriverName=Interbase;Database=C:\\Database\\TEST.GDB;RoleName=RoleName;User_Name=sysdba;Password=masterkey;SQLDialect=3;MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxReadOnlyMetaData,Version=11.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b;GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINTERBASE;LibraryName=Dbxint30.dll;VendorLib=GDS32.DLL";
            //GDS32.DLL
            //fbclient.dll
            return c;
        }

        public void ReadData(DbConnection conn) {
            string sql = "select * from user";
            DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            conn.Open();
            DbDataReader myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = myreader;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("user");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.Load(myreader, LoadOption.PreserveChanges, ds.Tables[0]);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            myreader.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right 32 or 64 bit one? there are 2 as I recall

Comment: InterBase Server and Interbase Console are 64 bit. ADO_NET 2_0 Driver for InterBase is 32 bit. If i compile the project as x86 i get the following error: "Borland.Data.TDBXError: 'DBX Error:  Driver could not be properly initialized.  Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system ". If I run it as x64 I get the following error: Borland.Data.TDBXError: 'Unable to load dbxint.dll (ErrorCode 193).  It may be missing from the system path.'

Comment: as I said.. you have to have the right one.. you will need to build in 32bit then